# Not able to connect with bluetooth device with socket in android studio

Tags: android, bluetooth, client

Hello everyone I am new to android development i am connecting with bluetooth device as a client in different class thread. If Nullpointerexcception occur then i use default UUID. After this when i use socket.connect() it show debug warning and don't send any pair request to device. Nothing happen. I am new to android development if any one can help. Thank you in advance.

**Warning and Logs**

[image: Warning and Logs]

here is my code in Thread;

```
class ConnectWithDevice(context : ConnectWithBluetooth, device : BluetoothDevice) : Thread(){

    private val mContext : ConnectWithBluetooth = context
    private val mmSocket : BluetoothSocket
    private val mmDevice : BluetoothDevice
    // Default UUID
    private val mmDefaultUUID = UUID.fromString("78c374fd-f84d-4a9e-aa5b-9b0b6292952e")

    init {
        var temp : BluetoothSocket? = null
        mmDevice = device
        try {
            temp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mmDevice.uuids[0].uuid)
        }catch (en : NullPointerException){
            en.printStackTrace()               
            temp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mmDefaultUUID)
        }catch (e : IOException){
            e.printStackTrace()
            Log.e("TAG","Socket's create() method failed",e)
        }
        mmSocket = temp!!
        Log.i("TAG","Got the Socket")
    }

    override fun run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it otherwise slows down the connection.
        if(mContext.bluetoothAdapter != null){
            mContext.bluetoothAdapter!!.cancelDiscovery()
        }

        try{
            // Connect to the remote device through the socket. This call blocks
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception.
            Log.i("TAG","Connecting...")
            mmSocket.connect()
            Log.i("TAG","Bluetooth Successfully Connected")
        }catch (connectException : IOException){
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and return.
            try{
                mmSocket.close()
            }catch (closeException : IOException){
                Log.e("TAG","Could not close the client socket",closeException)
            }
            return
        }
        // The connection attempt succeeded. Perform work associated with
        // the connection in a separate thread.
        Log.i("TAG","Device is Connected")
        //manageMyConnectedSocket(mmSocket)
    }

    // Closes the client socket and causes the thread to finish.
    // Call this method from the main activity to shut down the connection.
    fun cancel(){
        try {
            mmSocket.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.e(ContentValues.TAG, "Could not close the client socket", e)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i find the solution here it is ->
I use this code ->

```
val m = device.javaClass.getMethod("createRfcommSocket", *arrayOf<Class<*>>(Int::class.java))
            temp = m.invoke(device, 1) as BluetoothSocket
```

Instead of this ->

```
temp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(mmDevice.uuids[0].uuid)
```